# Material UI - Replicating the "required" text field error message

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple TextField component from Material UI in React (notice the "required")

```
<TextField
    label="Last name"
    name="lastName"
    required
    value={this.state.lastName}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

I love the functionality and appearance of the "required" property. It looks like this when it's activated:

[image: required field]

Unfortunately, this property is only available on their TextField component and not the RadioGroup or Select components. If I can at least replicate the appearance (and maybe the fact that it scrolls the page to the location of the input), I can apply it to all of my inputs for a consistent UI.

Does anyone know where they are getting the appearance from? It looks like it may be from a different package. Any help in finding it would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone wondering the same thing regarding Material UI, <Radio required /> has the same effect. Still working on figuring out one for the <Select /> component.

Comment: <Select native required /> works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a property of input from vanilla html. Textfield is composed of smaller components and Input is one of the components they use. The required property will trigger the dialog to appear.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
              Username: <input type="text" name="username" required>
              <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This snippet will also produce the same message.

Answer (score 6):

Actually is fairly easy to change the styles for the errors that the different browsers show whenever a form is validated. Here your friend is the [Constraint API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation).

There is an `invalid` event that will be fired before a form is submitted that checks if the elements that have the `required` attribute satisfy or not its constrains .

What I normally do is to use the [`onInvalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninvalid) event handler and pass a callback where you can get a lot of info about the validation.

For example in `event.target.validationMessage` you'll see the "Please fill out this field" or the `event.target.validity.valid` will tell you if the element is valid or not. Bear in mind that you have to `preventDefault` the `event`.

`e.preventDefault();
setInvalid( e.target.validity.valid );
setMessage( e.target.validationMessage );`

This is how I've styled the native HTML errors using the `<SnackbarContent />` component from `material-ui`.

[image]

Also, just to mention that CSS has a couple of pseudo elements that will help you to style the input. `:invalid` and `:valid` but this has nothing to do with the message itself.

Because this styles inconsistency really bugged me a time ago I created a `npm` plugin that deals with this for you, [pretty-form-error](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-form-error) it works with React and at least Angular 1.x.x

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to the "Please fill out this field" it looks like this might be a browser specific feature rather than a Material feature... Have you checked other browsers to see if this behaviour is reproducible?

Comment: Good idea! I checked Firefox and it does indeed display differently than Chrome

Comment: It would be because of the `required` attribute in the input field... browsers handle these things very differently... if you want a consistent experience then consider not using it... however you will have to get around the validation...